# Laravel returning a response with params

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-blade, param

I want to do something like this:

```
return Response::view('survey.do')
              //->with('theme',$survey->theme);
              ->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
              ->header('Expires', 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

It says it can't find the theme definition in the view, problem is when i do:

```
View::make('survey.do')->with('theme',$survey->theme)
```

It does work but I can't access the `http response` header, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `with` and `header` pass arrays like this:

```
$data = array('theme' => $survey->theme);

$headres = array(
    'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
    'Expires' => 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'
);

return Response::view('survey.do', $data, '200', $headres);
```

This will work because this is the method signature/header in the `Response` class (Facade):

```
public static function view($view, $data = array(), $status = 200, array $headers = array())
```

In this case, it calls the `make` method of that class which is as follows:

```
public static function make($content = '', $status = 200, array $headers = array())
{
    return new IlluminateResponse($content, $status, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'r on a good way. Put the view & header in a variable first:

```
$view = View::make('survey.do')
    ->with('theme', $survey->theme);

$response = Response::make($view, $status);
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate')
         ->header('Expires', 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

return $response;
```